# How to map angularfire2 list to an usable result

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm new on Angular 2 and i'm facing some troubles. I have the following realtime database:

[image: realtime Database]

I'm retrieving the data using the following code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
pacientes: AngularFireList<any[]>;
private Hospital:{
    Fichas: {},
    Pacientes: {},
    Profissionais:{},
    nome: string
};
constructor(private authService : AuthService, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {       

}

logout(){
    this.authService.logout();
}

getHospital() : AngularFireList<any[]>{
    return this.db.list('Hospital',ref => ref.orderByChild('nome').equalTo('Santa Clara'));
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.getHospital().valueChanges().map(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

}

(I know that this function should be at services.ts). I want to iterate with ngFor at 'Pacientes' but I don't know how to do it. Do I have to map the result to the variable Hospital? If yes, how can I map this result to something usable at my html?

Thanks.

!!!!EDIT!!!!!!

I'm doing like this:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
pacientes: Array<any> = [];
medicosResponsaveis: any;
subscription: any;
constructor(private authService : AuthService, private db: DatabaseService) {       

}

logout(){
    this.authService.logout();
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.db.getHospital().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.pacientes = Object.keys(data[0].Pacientes).map((key)=>{ return data[0].Pacientes[key]});
        });
}
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

}

Is it right? All the names are printing with ngFor. Another question, how can I add the Paciente json key along with all the others values of the array?

Comment: still you have not solved this?

Comment: No, unfortunately

Comment: *ngFor="let pacient of Object.keys(this.pacients)" and save the pacients variable on the class